# Objective-c multiple class implementation in one .m file

Tags: objective-c, class, linker, implementation

I would like to compile multiple classes (classA, classB and classC) in a single .m file :

```
@implementation ClassA
static ClassA *singletonClassA = nil;
+ (ClassA *) GetSingleton
{        
    /* some code */
}
@end

@implementation ClassB
static ClassB *singletonClassB = nil;
+ (ClassB *) GetSingleton
{        
    /* some code */
}
@end

@implementation ClassC
static ClassC *singletonClassC = nil;
+ (ClassC *) GetSingleton
{        
    /* some code */
}
@end
```

I compile to static library (.a file) successfully.

But when I explore . a file, I only see ClassA implementation !

Any help ?

Comment: There isn't anything wrong with that.  If you link the library with some code that uses it, does it work?

Comment: No, it doesn't  work : I have ClassB and ClassC linking problem, linker does not find it !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oups, sorry !

I asked my question too early !

I had a problem of project cleaninig, my .m was not updated and only classA was impemented !

Sorry about that !

Answer (score 0):

@class classA,classB,classC;
@implementation ClassA

.......
......

then rest out code .